# Backup a folder using Applescript

Tags: applescript, directory

I'm new to Applescript, and am trying to put together a simple script to backup some folders when it is run. My script is as follows:

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        set backupFolder to make new folder at "BACKUP" with properties {name:(year of (current date) as string) & "-" & (month of (current date) as integer as string) & "-" & (day of (current date) as string)}
        duplicate folder "~/Test" to backupFolder
    end tell
end run
```

However, when I run the script I recieve an error stating that:

```
Finder got an error: Can’t set folder "2013-1-9" of disk "BACKUP" to folder "~/Test".
```

This seems like such a trivial problem, but I can't work out how to fix it. Would anyone be able to let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript doesn't understand `"~/Test"` (or even `"/Users/username/Test/"`) most of the time.

```
set d to (year of (current date) as text) & "-" & (month of (current date) as integer as text) & "-" & (day of (current date) as text)
tell application "Finder"
    set f to make new folder at POSIX file "/Users/username/Backups/" with properties {name:d}
    duplicate POSIX file "/Users/username/Test/" to f
end tell
```

`/Users/username` can be replaced with `system attribute "HOME"`. You can also use HFS paths (like `"Macintosh HD:Users:username:Test"`) directly.

It would be easier to do with a shell script though:

```
d=~/Backup/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/
mkdir -p $d
cp -R ~/Test $d
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your duplicate... line with the following:

```
duplicate folder POSIX file "~/Test" to backupFolder
```

Comment: Tip: %F is shortcut for %Y-%m-%d. So: d=~/Backup/$(date +%F)/